# in R, How to sum by flowing row in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have df(A) (ncol=1,nrow=1356)

```
col1
 5
 7
 9
 3
 2
 3.8
 24
 2.7
 12
 11
 23
 .... to 1356 row...
```

i would like the sum from the first row to the fifth row, and after from the second row to the seventh row, and so on. Furthermore each value is moltiplicate for a fraction of the number of row. The expected results is, for example:

```
5*1/5 + 7*2/5 + 9*3/5 + 3*4/5 + 2*5/5= (result)
7*1/5 + 9*2/5 + 3*3/5 + 2*4/5 + 3.8*5/5= (result)
9*1/5 + 3*2/5 + 2*3/5 + 3.8*4/5 + 24*5/5= (result)
and so on for the 1356 row
```

In synthesis the sum is every 5 row, roll the data row by row. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anything you already tried?

Comment: Perhaps `library(data.table); m1 <- na.omit(do.call(cbind, shift(df1$col1, 0:4, type="lead"))); rowSums(m1*(1:5)[col(m1)]/5)`

Comment: For the moment only the apply function, but the result is differet respect what i would want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
m1 <- na.omit(do.call(cbind, shift(df1$col1, 0:4, type="lead")))
rowSums(m1*(1:5)[col(m1)]/5) 
#[1] 13.60 12.20 31.24 25.58 30.48 32.58 44.88
```

---

Or another option

```
 m1 <- embed(df1$col1,5)
 rowSums(m1*(5:1)[col(m1)]/5)
 #[1] 13.60 12.20 31.24 25.58 30.48 32.58 44.88
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use my favorite R function, `filter`:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "col1
                 5
                 7
                 9
                 3
                 2
                 3.8
                 24
                 2.7
                 12
                 11
                 23", header = TRUE)

5*1/5 + 7*2/5 + 9*3/5 + 3*4/5 + 2*5/5
#[1] 13.6
7*1/5 + 9*2/5 + 3*3/5 + 2*4/5 + 3.8*5/5
#[1] 12.2
9*1/5 + 3*2/5 + 2*3/5 + 3.8*4/5 + 24*5/5
#[1] 31.24

c(na.omit(stats::filter(DF$col1, (5:1)/5)))
#[1] 13.60 12.20 31.24 25.58 30.48 32.58 44.88
```