# Conditionally selecting columns in dplyr where certain proportion of values is NA

Tags: r, filter, dataframe, dplyr, na

## Data

I'm working with a data set resembling the `data.frame` generated below:

```
set.seed(1)
dta <- data.frame(observation = 1:20,
                  valueA = runif(n = 20),
                  valueB = runif(n = 20),
                  valueC = runif(n = 20),
                  valueD = runif(n = 20))
dta[2:5,3] <- NA
dta[2:10,4] <- NA
dta[7:20,5] <- NA
```

The columns have `NA` values with the last column having more than 60% of observations `NAs`.

```
> sapply(dta, function(x) {table(is.na(x))})
$observation

FALSE 
   20 

$valueA

FALSE 
   20 

$valueB

FALSE  TRUE 
   16     4 

$valueC

FALSE  TRUE 
   11     9 

$valueD

FALSE  TRUE 
    6    14
```

## Problem

I would like to be able to remove this column in `dplyr` pipe line somehow passing it to the `select` argument.

### Attempts

This can be easily done in `base`. For example to select columns with less than *50%* `NAs` I can do:

```
dta[, colSums(is.na(dta)) < nrow(dta) / 2]
```

which produces:

```
> head(dta[, colSums(is.na(dta)) < nrow(dta) / 2], 2)
  observation    valueA    valueB    valueC
1           1 0.2655087 0.9347052 0.8209463
2           2 0.3721239        NA        NA
```

---

### Task

I'm interested in achieving the same flexibility in `dplyr` pipe line:

```
Vectorize(require)(package = c("dplyr",         # Data manipulation
                               "magrittr"),     # Reverse pipe

char = TRUE)

dta %<>%
  # Some transformations I'm doing on the data
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric)) %>% 
  # I want my select to take place here
```

Comment: You can use `Filter` i.e. `Filter(function(x) sum(is.na(x)) < length(x)/2, dta)`

Comment: @akrun As always, thanks for the helpful contribution. I was just wondering, isn't the `filter` supposed to be dropping the observations? I'm interested in removing columns not rows.

Comment: It is removing the columns i.e. `Filter` with capital `F`

Comment: @akrun Now, I got you `?Filter != ?filter` :)

Comment: @akrun One more question with respect to the suggest `Filter` solution, I see that you are passing the `dta` object, on my real data I'm applying some transformations to the data (like `gather` and `spread`) so in effect the object I'm working on does not correspond to the initial `dta` frame. This is why I added this `mutate_each(funs(as.numeric)) %>%` in my example to indicate that I'm working on a transformed `dta`. In effect, I don't really have `dta` to pass on, just a transformed `data.frame` after applying a couple of pipes.

Comment: I added a solution with `summarise_each`.  Perhaps it helps you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like this perhaps?

```
dta %>% select(which(colMeans(is.na(.)) < 0.5)) %>% head
#  observation    valueA    valueB    valueC
#1           1 0.2655087 0.9347052 0.8209463
#2           2 0.3721239        NA        NA
#3           3 0.5728534        NA        NA
#4           4 0.9082078        NA        NA
#5           5 0.2016819        NA        NA
#6           6 0.8983897 0.3861141        NA
```

**Updated** with `colMeans` instead of `colSums` which means you don't need to divide by the number of rows any more.

And, just for the record, in base R you could also use `colMeans`:

```
dta[,colMeans(is.na(dta)) < 0.5]
```

Answer (score 15):

Update for 2020 perhaps, now that `dplyr` reached 1.0.0, which incorporates `where()`:

```r
dta %>% select(where(function(x) sum(is.na(x)) / length(x) < 0.5))
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this does the job:

```
dta %>% select_if(~mean(is.na(.)) < 0.5) %>% head() 


 observation    valueA    valueB    valueC
  1           0.2655087 0.9347052 0.8209463
  2           0.3721239        NA        NA
  3           0.5728534        NA        NA
  4           0.9082078        NA        NA
  5           0.2016819        NA        NA
  6           0.8983897 0.3861141        NA
```

`

Answer (score 5):

We can use `extract` from `magrittr` after getting a logical vector with `summarise_each/unlist`

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
dta %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.)) < n()/2)) %>% 
    unlist() %>%
    extract(dta,.)
```

---

Or use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(is.na(x)) < length(x)/2, dta)
```

Or a slightly compact option is

```
Filter(function(x) mean(is.na(x)) < 0.5, dta)
```

Comment: I kind of fail to understand this whole question. Seems like `dta[colMeans(is.na(dta)) < .5]` is the most concise/vectorized/simple/readable solution, what's the point in all these `Filter` or `dplyr/magrittr` stuff? I'm probably getting old.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You do understand that `colMeans`, `colSums` etc convert the data to `matrix`.  It may not be that efficient (may be I am wrong).  But, I like `Filter` because it adds an exotic touch to it (just like `filter` in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851754/in-r-how-to-sum-by-flowing-row-in-a-data-frame/34852022#34852022).  Other than that, `magrittr` stuff is only for `dplyr/magritr` fans (my humble opinion).

Comment: Actually `is.na` already converts to a matrix. `col*` functions already operate on the matrix. Thus we could do `dta[colMeans(sapply(dta, is.na)) < .5]` if you like and its still very readable. And in that linked question, `filter` is actually the most concise/vectorized/simple solution, rather an exotic one. But I guess you are not the address here for my grange.

Comment: @DavidArenburg The question is about delivering the transformation within the `dplyr` pipeline. I reckon that `base` solution may prove more efficient in this case but my ambition was to undertake this transformation *within* the `dplyr` pipe line. This mostly motivated by personal preference to undertake this transformation along other ones within the `dplyr` scope, which mostly results in a code presentation and R script that suits me better. I agree that `base` could prove more efficient but. I also like @akrun's idea of adding the *exotic touch* to the solution.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the dplyr solution `dta %>% select(which(colMeans(is.na(.)) < 0.5))` is the same as what you describe as most vectorized/concise/... approach _except_ for a call to `which` - are you really worried about that? To me, it's perfectly understandable that OP is asking specifically for a "piped" answer since this fits their workflow. It's not about seeking the maximum performance. And even if they were, I reckon it's rather unlikely that this column-subsetting operation would be an actual performance bottleneck in real world programs.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Exactly - it's the same solution just using an unnecessary/irrelevant calls to an additional packages/functions (IMO). That reminds me of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311771/when-is-it-ok-to-post-an-answer-that-requires-a-new-r-package/311880#311880). But, as I said - I guess I'm just getting old.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you still don't understand it (or maybe you don't want to?) It's about workflow and they're specifically using dplyr anyway. In that sense, using base for this subset would be an interruption

Comment: @DavidArenburg I can also add that this transformation is part of much longer workflow, including charting at the end. In effect those transformations are only applied for the purpose of generating a specific change, so leaving on side performance issue, it makes sense for the code to read more less on the lines *take master data -> do a few things on it -> generate chart*. It simply makes a nice, I would day more concise read. As *by teaching, we learn* rightfully pointed out is mostly about the workflow than anything else. In my defence, I would say that to an extent it's question of taste.

Answer (score 0):

With `purrr::keep`

```
library(dplyr); library(purrr)
dta %>% keep(~ sum(is.na(.))/length(.) < 0.5)
```

```r
   observation     valueA     valueB     valueC
1            1 0.26550866 0.93470523 0.82094629
2            2 0.37212390         NA         NA
3            3 0.57285336         NA         NA
4            4 0.90820779         NA         NA
5            5 0.20168193         NA         NA
6            6 0.89838968 0.38611409         NA
7            7 0.94467527 0.01339033         NA
8            8 0.66079779 0.38238796         NA
9            9 0.62911404 0.86969085         NA
10          10 0.06178627 0.34034900         NA
11          11 0.20597457 0.48208012 0.47761962
12          12 0.17655675 0.59956583 0.86120948
13          13 0.68702285 0.49354131 0.43809711
14          14 0.38410372 0.18621760 0.24479728
15          15 0.76984142 0.82737332 0.07067905
16          16 0.49769924 0.66846674 0.09946616
17          17 0.71761851 0.79423986 0.31627171
18          18 0.99190609 0.10794363 0.51863426
19          19 0.38003518 0.72371095 0.66200508
20          20 0.77744522 0.41127443 0.40683019
```